# Work with JAVA SE and JAVA EE in Eclipse at the same time

Tags: eclipse

I'm working with `Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers` on Ubuntu, to developpe Java EE applications.

In the other hand, I use `Eclipse Platform` which I downloaded from the Ubuntu Software Center to developpe Java SE applications.

I want to use one single Eclipse to developpe the both Java SE and Java EE, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do both tasks into the same Eclipse installation, provided that the same installation have the required plugins to do those tasks.

In principle, **"Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers"** (which contains many other features than the standard Eclipse installation) should be enough to also allow you to develop **Java SE** applications.

P.D: The list of all the features for the "Eclipse Java EE IDE for web developers" may be found [here](http://goo.gl/oVkXzz)